# Is there a stacky definition of irreducible symplectic manifold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, derived-algebraic-geometry

I am now interested in studying symplectic structures in the field of stacks.

In particular, is there a stacky definition of irreducible symplectic manifold ?
I'm also interested in similar things in derived algebraic geometry.

Any comment welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.05632.pdf. In page number 7, they define Symplectic stacks.  It might be of some use.. You can also look at http://marle.perso.math.cnrs.fr/publications/Liegroupoids.pdf This define/discuss symplectic Lie groupoids. It is not necessary to remind that Lie groupoids and differentible stacks are closely related.. :)

Comment: There is a relatively large body of recent literature on derived (shifted) sympectic structures - look in works of a subset of Calanque, Pantev, Toen, Vaquie, Vezzosi, etc. A review is in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02753.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much!  And what is the difference between the definition on the third page of http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6294v1 and the shifted Symplectic structures?

Comment: I apologize for the many questions, but I would be grateful if you could also give me some good literature for learning derived algebraic geometry and shifted symplectic structures.

Comment: The definition you mention in arxiv.org/abs/1111.6294v1 looks like an attempt at a $0$-shifted symplectic structure, but seems to omit any sort of closure condition. Beware that the survey arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02753.pdf which Balazs mentions really just summarises CPTVV, neglecting to mention much related literature. For differentiable stacks, a summary on shifted structures is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07622 , including references to related mathematical physics papers. Some of Safronov's papers are also a good place to look if you want to see where these structures arise in the wild.

Comment: Thank you very much! Does that mean that the result of TPVV can lead to the result of http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6294v1 ?

Comment: yes, by throwing away the higher structure

Comment: Many times Thank you. And what are the open problems with shifted symplectic structure?